# Problema con funciones y objetos en Python

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo una función que almacena un valor en un objeto y quiero, en otra función externa a esa función, hacer uso de ese mismo objeto pero soy incapaz de saber cómo gestionarlo.

Algo de ejemplo sería:
La función A pide un input de una frase y separa las palabras en una lista, almacenándolas en una variable X.
La función B coge esa variable X y une las palabras en un string que luego almacena en una variable Y.
La función C imprime esa variable Y.

Como veis es un ejemplo muy absurdo pero es por poner algo básico y que sea entendible.

Comment: El mecanismo de comunicación entre funciones son los parámetros y los valores retornados. En tu ejemplo, la función A pide el input, genera la lista **y retorna la lista**. La función B, si llama ella misma a la función A, lo haría con algo como `resultado = A()`, y así tendría la lista en la variable resultado. Lo juntaría para crear una cadena y **retorna la cadena**. La función C haría `txt = B()` para obtener esa cadena y guardarla en `txt` tras lo que ya puede hacer `print(cadena)`. Como ves cada función tiene su propia variable, no accede directamente a las variables creadas en otras.

Comment: También pudiera ser que la función B(), tenga como misión simplemente unir palabras de una lista en un string, pero esa lista le venga de otro sitio, en vez de la función A(). Entonces B() no llamaría a A(), sino que recibiría la lista con la que quiere operar como parámetro. `def B(lista): ...`. En este caso haría falta una función "principal" que vaya llamando a las otras en el orden correcto. Así esa función principal podría hacer `lst = A()` y después `txt = B(lst)`

Comment: ¡¡Mil gracias por las respuestas!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow Héctor c:

Puedes hacerlo usando la sentencia return, que le dice a la función que valor debe devolver la función. Por default, toda función de Python devuelve None, pero ahora veremos como cambiar eso.

Este es el código que cumple con las espectativas de tu ejemplo:

```
def a():
    # Pido la frase al usuario
    x = input("Ingrese una frase: ")

    # Separo la frase en una lista de palabras.
    # Al NO pasar argumentos a split, le digo que separe cada palabra segun espacios
    # Ej: "hola  mundo genial" se separa en ["hola", "mundo", "genial"]
    x = x.split()

    # hago que la función devuelva la variable x
    return x


# La función b recibe la variable x como primer argumento y trabaja con ella.
def b(x):
    # uno cada palabra por una coma
    y = ",".join(x)

    return y

# La función c recibe a y como primer argumento y trabaja con ella.
def c(y):
    print(y)



# Guardo lo devuelto por la función a en x
x = a()

# Paso x a la función b y guardo el valor devuelto en y
y = b(x)

# Ejecuto la función c
c(y)
```

Como dijo @abulafia, las llamadas a las funciones pueden estar unas dentro de otras y (cito de Abulafia) "ahorrarte variables intermedias" (yo las separé para que pudieras entender mejor como funciona).
Eso significa que puedes hacer `c(b(a()))` y obtener el mismo resultado!

Comment: ¡¡Muchísimas gracias!! ^^

Comment: Buena respuesta! Para rematar podrías añadir que las llamadas pueden anidarse para ahorrar variables intermedias, y por tanto el ejemplo final quedar como `c(b(a()))`

Comment: @abulafia gracias! c: Y gracias por avisarme, estaba considerando agregarlo.

Comment: Un placer @HéctorPrietodelaCalle ^^

Comment: @DanteS. Disculpa si soy muy puntilloso, pero en lo que has añadido, al decir "las funciones pueden estar unas dentro de otras", podría entenderse que te refieres a las definiciones (que también podrían anidarse, pero ese es otro cantar). Mejor decir que las llamadas pueden ponerse una dentro de otra, para que el resultado devuelto por una pase como parámetro a otra.

Comment: Buena idea @abulafia! No hay de que disculparse, tus avisos son de ayuda c: